# How to close a modal in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am unable to close a modal. I am displaying few images inside it, and onPress of the "X(close)" icon, want to close the modal. I have tried setting the state of modalvisible to false, by default which is set to true. But on press of icon the modal doesn't gets closed. Any solution would be of great help.

```
 export default class imagenav extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    state = {
      modalVisible: false,
  }
}
openmodal(){
  this.setState(modalVisible: true)
}

render() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Modal  onRequestClose={() => {}}> 
      <GallerySwiper
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "black" }}
          images={[
            {source: {uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png",

              dimensions: {width: 1080, height: 1920}}
          },
          ]}
      />
      <Header
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              borderBottomWidth: 0,
            }}
          > 
      <Right>
              <Icon
                name='close'
                color='white'
                onPress={() => {
                   this.setState({
                    modalVisible: false,
                  })  

                  console.log("getting closed");

                }} 
              />
              </Right>
              </Header>

      </Modal>
      </Container>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to put a state for it in visible as bellow:

```
<Modal onRequestClose={()=> null} visible={this.state.active} transparent={true}>

       /////your Views and things to show in modal


</Modal>
```

in your state you have to make it as blew:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state =  {
          active:false,
        }

      }
```

And then you have to toggle it in an onPress for example:

```
   onPress=()={
       this.setState({active:true})
    }
```

So totally in your project you will have:

```
 export default class imagenav extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        state = {
          modalVisible: false,
      }
    }
    openmodal(){
      this.setState({modalVisible: true})
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <Container>
          <Modal  visible={this.state.modalVisible} onRequestClose={() => {}}> 
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <GallerySwiper
              style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "black" }}
              images={[
                {source: {uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png",

                  dimensions: {width: 1080, height: 1920}}
              },
              ]}
          />
          <Header
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: 'black',
                  borderBottomWidth: 0,
                }}
              > 
          <Right>
                  <Icon
                    name='close'
                    color='white'
                    onPress={() => {
                       this.setState({
                        modalVisible: false,
                      })  

                      console.log("getting closed");

                    }} 
                  />
                  </Right>
                  </Header>
           </View>

          </Modal>
          </Container>
      );
    }
    }
```

**Update:** 
According to your last request there is a way. You can pass flag to your next screen and in the componentDidMount() of next screen you can check it. if it is true you can show the modal otherwise ignore it.

I hope I could help. :)

Comment: Hi Reza! The modal is getting closed. But I am unable to get the data from the previous screen on close. The modal opens up when users click on an image button in the previous screen, and then it navigates to the class containing gallery swiper.

Comment: Can you help me out on this??

Comment: @AbhirupMukherjee: In fact you can not open a modal from pervious screen. Because the component becomes unmount and your states disappears after unmounting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline `if` to only render your modal is your state allows it :

```
{this.state.modalVisible && 
    <Modal onRequestClose={() => { }}>
        <GallerySwiper
            style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "black" }}
            images={[
                {
                    source: {
                        uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png",

                        dimensions: { width: 1080, height: 1920 }
                    }
                },
            ]}
        />
        <Header
            style={{
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                borderBottomWidth: 0,
            }}
        >
            <Right>
                <Icon
                    name='close'
                    color='white'
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            modalVisible: false,
                        })

                        console.log("getting closed");

                    }}
                />
            </Right>
        </Header>
    </Modal>
}
```

Comment: Hi, i tried using your solution. But i'm getting an TypeError: Cannot read property 'modalvisible' of null.

Answer (score 0):

You have a state, but you are not using it

`<Modal onRequestClose={()=> this.openmodal(false)} visible={this.state.modalVisible}>` should be good to go.

oh and your openmodal function can be used for opening and closing the modal

```
openmodal(value){
  this.setState({modalVisible: value})
}

<Icon
                    name='close'
                    color='white'
                    onPress={() => {
                      this.openmodal(false)   
                      console.log("getting closed");
                    }} 
                  />
```